# Javascript download multiple files with iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to download multiple files with one button "download all",I don't want to zip them, i want to download them with javascript and hidden iframe,how I can do it? here is the example with iframe and javascript ,but I don't understand what url I need to send to ifrm.setAttribute( "src", url ) ;What is 'somefile.do'?

```
function makeFrame( url ) 
{ 
    ifrm = document.createElement( "IFRAME" ); 
    ifrm.setAttribute( "style", "display:none;" ) ;
    ifrm.setAttribute( "src", url ) ; 
    ifrm.style.width = 0+"px"; 
    ifrm.style.height = 0+"px"; 
    document.body.appendChild( ifrm ) ; 
}  

function downloadChecked( )
{
    for( i = 0 ; i < document.downloadform.elements.length ; i++ )
    {
        foo = document.downloadform.elements[ i ] ;
        if( foo.type == "checkbox" && foo.checked == true )
        {
            makeFrame('somefile.do?command=download&fileid=' + foo.name );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to open as many iframes as files you have and the user will need to confirm them one by one. Is that the intended flow?

Comment: Yes,and there are files from many types .xls,xml,doc.Is it possible?I am just new in javascript..

Comment: Yes, but if you will have, for example, some plugin in browser to display those files directly, not download them, nothing happen. In that case, you should make some handler.php, which will send all files as attachements and will accept file names as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass direct file URL (or URL which cause direct downloading) into iframe src. In your script case, **somefile.do** is probably some download handler and file ID and action is passed by it's parameters.

But back to your question, if you have files:

- example.com/file1.zip
- example.com/file2.zip
- example.com/file3.zip

You have to pass it just into `makeFrame` function as a parameter:

```
makeFrame('http://example.com/file1.zip');
```

It will create iframe for every URL and start downloading (or display save dialog - depends on browser). Make sure to have files URLs in array and pass them in for loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [**multiDownload**](https://github.com/biesiad/multiDownload) jQuery plugin. It's also using iframes, and keeps your code tidy.

**Example**:

```
<a href="document1.zip" class="document">document 1</a>
<a href="document2.zip" class="document">document 2</a>
<a href="document3.zip" class="document">document 3</a>

<a href="#" id="download_all">download all</a>

$('#download_all').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.document').multiDownload();
});
```

And you're ready :)

Comment: If you also have IE 11 in your target browser list, then this will not work in it!