# Downloading multiple files with a data URI

Tags: html, download, data-uri

I know how to setup a href and a download attribute on an anchor to allow a user to download data as a file.

However, a client has requested that one link download two files together AND not be zipped!  Don't ask me why!

Looking online I found the following solutions:

1) create 2 iframes on the fly and in each's form set its GET to the location of one of the files on the server, then run a form submit...[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339440/download-multiple-files-with-a-single-action)

2) A variation of (1) using a JQuery plugin..[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113866/javascript-download-multiple-files-with-iframe)

3) Opening popup windows. (not worth the link)

I'm wondering if I can handle this on the JS side?  In the same App, I'm exporting data to CSV with the following code:

```
$elm.attr('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(_str)).attr('download', fileName);
```

Where _str is a flattened two dimensional array.

Can I somehow trail or attach a second file to that?

Answer (score 1):

You can create links on the fly and fire navite click event.

```
function downloadAll(files){
    if(files.length == 0) return;
    file = files.pop();
    var theAnchor = $('<a />')
        .attr('href', file[1])
        .attr('download',file[0]);
    theAnchor[0].click(); 
    theAnchor.remove();
    downloadAll(files);
}

$('a.download-csv').on('click', function(){
    downloadAll([

        ['file1.csv', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,'+ 
                     encodeURIComponent('my,csv,file\and,so,on')],

        ['file2.csv', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,'+ 
                     encodeURIComponent('my,csv,file\and,so,on')],

        ['file3.csv', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,'+ 
                     encodeURIComponent('my,csv,file\and,so,on')]

    ]);
});
```

Here you can find the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/diegolamonica/ssk8z9pa/) with a working demo.

Here is the [article on my web site](http://diegolamonica.info/multiple-files-download-on-single-link-click/) with all the details